# Java: Method signature

Tags: java

I want to make an interface `Mergeable` that declares a method `merge()`.  A class that implements this will have to implement the method like follows:

**SomeObject.java**

```
public class SomeObject implements Mergeable

    @Override
    public SomeObject merge(SomeObject other) {...}
```

See that the return and parameter type are set to the implementing class.  Is there a way to enforce this and how would I set the method signature in the interface?

Comment: why do you want to enforce a method which returns only one type of object  and declare it in interface?

Comment: Use generics, something like `<T>` in your interface.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar the method should return the type of whichever class implements it.  So if I have another class Y it should return Y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `Comparable` interface for an example.  You'll probably have to write something like

```
interface Mergeable<T> {
   T merge(T other);
}
```

...and then anytime you want to accept something `Mergeable`, write

```
<T extends Mergeable<T>> void somethingWithMergeables(T merge1) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why not `interface Mergeable<T extends Mergeable<T>>`?

Comment: That'd work, too, but you'd need to use the same constraint anyway.  It doesn't get you much, really.